# How do I create a tab bar at the center of the screen?

Tags: flutter

I tried to call up the summary page but everything disappear when I put expanded:

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════ Null check operator used on a null
> value The relevant error-causing widget was Column
> lib\screens\consult_profile.dart:28
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by scheduler library
> ═════════════════════════════════ Updated layout information required
> for RenderRepaintBoundary#d8a53 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT to calculate
> semantics. 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 2647 pos 12: '!_needsLayout'

The source code is:

```
class MyCoolPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyCoolPage> createState() => _MyCoolPageState();
  }

  class _MyCoolPageState extends State<MyCoolPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
      child: SizedBox(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 500,
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              ),
              child: AppBar(
                bottom: TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: [
                    Text(
                      "Summary",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Reservations",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    color: b,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  ),
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
           // create widgets for each tab bar here

            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
               controller: _tabController,
                children: [
            
                // first tab bar view widget

                  Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: MyLovelySummary(),
                    ),
                  ),
               // second tab bar view widget

                  Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: MyLovelyReservations(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```